# Compiling error: syntax error in VERSION script

Tags: grep, libtool

I am trying to compile the C bindings for Zookeeper, but I am unable to do so. When I run make, I receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: ignoring invalid character `\033' in script
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: ignoring invalid character `3' in script
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: ignoring invalid character `5' in script
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: syntax error in VERSION script
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The entire output for `./configure` and `make` are attached below.

Can anyone help me on how I can resolve this issue?

```
$ ./configure
checking for doxygen... no
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for dot... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for cppunit-config... /usr/bin/cppunit-config
checking for Cppunit - version >= 1.10.2... 1.13.1
checking for generated/zookeeper.jute.c... yes
checking for generated/zookeeper.jute.h... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for pthread_mutex_lock in -lpthread... yes
configure: building with SyncAPI support
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for nfds_t... yes
checking whether to enable ipv6... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getlogin... yes
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for getuid... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for poll... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strtol... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/installs/zookeeper-3.4.6/src/c'
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zookeeper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zookeeper.Tpo -c -o zookeeper.lo `test -f 'src/zookeeper.c' || echo './'`src/zookeeper.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zookeeper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zookeeper.Tpo -c src/zookeeper.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zookeeper.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zookeeper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zookeeper.Tpo -c src/zookeeper.c -o zookeeper.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/zookeeper.Tpo .deps/zookeeper.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT recordio.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/recordio.Tpo -c -o recordio.lo `test -f 'src/recordio.c' || echo './'`src/recordio.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT recordio.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/recordio.Tpo -c src/recordio.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/recordio.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT recordio.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/recordio.Tpo -c src/recordio.c -o recordio.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/recordio.Tpo .deps/recordio.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zookeeper.jute.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zookeeper.jute.Tpo -c -o zookeeper.jute.lo `test -f 'generated/zookeeper.jute.c' || echo './'`generated/zookeeper.jute.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zookeeper.jute.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zookeeper.jute.Tpo -c generated/zookeeper.jute.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zookeeper.jute.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zookeeper.jute.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zookeeper.jute.Tpo -c generated/zookeeper.jute.c -o zookeeper.jute.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/zookeeper.jute.Tpo .deps/zookeeper.jute.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zk_log.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zk_log.Tpo -c -o zk_log.lo `test -f 'src/zk_log.c' || echo './'`src/zk_log.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zk_log.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zk_log.Tpo -c src/zk_log.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zk_log.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zk_log.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zk_log.Tpo -c src/zk_log.c -o zk_log.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/zk_log.Tpo .deps/zk_log.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zk_hashtable.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zk_hashtable.Tpo -c -o zk_hashtable.lo `test -f 'src/zk_hashtable.c' || echo './'`src/zk_hashtable.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zk_hashtable.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zk_hashtable.Tpo -c src/zk_hashtable.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zk_hashtable.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT zk_hashtable.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zk_hashtable.Tpo -c src/zk_hashtable.c -o zk_hashtable.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/zk_hashtable.Tpo .deps/zk_hashtable.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT st_adaptor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/st_adaptor.Tpo -c -o st_adaptor.lo `test -f 'src/st_adaptor.c' || echo './'`src/st_adaptor.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT st_adaptor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/st_adaptor.Tpo -c src/st_adaptor.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/st_adaptor.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT st_adaptor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/st_adaptor.Tpo -c src/st_adaptor.c -o st_adaptor.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/st_adaptor.Tpo .deps/st_adaptor.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE   -o libzkst.la  zookeeper.lo recordio.lo zookeeper.jute.lo zk_log.lo zk_hashtable.lo st_adaptor.lo -lm 
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libzkst.a .libs/zookeeper.o .libs/recordio.o .libs/zookeeper.jute.o .libs/zk_log.o .libs/zk_hashtable.o .libs/st_adaptor.o 
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libzkst.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libzkst.la" && ln -s "../libzkst.la" "libzkst.la" )
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT hashtable_itr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashtable_itr.Tpo -c -o hashtable_itr.lo `test -f 'src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c' || echo './'`src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT hashtable_itr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashtable_itr.Tpo -c src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/hashtable_itr.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT hashtable_itr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashtable_itr.Tpo -c src/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c -o hashtable_itr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/hashtable_itr.Tpo .deps/hashtable_itr.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./tests -I./generated  -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT hashtable.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashtable.Tpo -c -o hashtable.lo `test -f 'src/hashtable/hashtable.c' || echo './'`src/hashtable/hashtable.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT hashtable.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashtable.Tpo -c src/hashtable/hashtable.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/hashtable.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./tests -I./generated -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT hashtable.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashtable.Tpo -c src/hashtable/hashtable.c -o hashtable.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/hashtable.Tpo .deps/hashtable.Plo
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE   -o libhashtable.la  hashtable_itr.lo hashtable.lo  
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libhashtable.a .libs/hashtable_itr.o .libs/hashtable.o 
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libhashtable.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libhashtable.la" && ln -s "../libhashtable.la" "libhashtable.la" )
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Werror  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -no-undefined -version-info 2 -export-symbols-regex '(zoo_|zookeeper_|zhandle|Z|format_log_message|log_message|logLevel|deallocate_|zerror|is_unrecoverable)'  -o libzookeeper_st.la -rpath /home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/installs/build/zookeeper-cbinding/lib  libzkst.la libhashtable.la 
libtool: link: /usr/bin/nm -B   ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a | sed -n -e 's/^.*[     ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[     ][  ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' | /bin/sed 's/.* //' | sort | uniq > .libs/libzookeeper_st.exp
libtool: link: /bin/grep -E -e "(zoo_|zookeeper_|zhandle|Z|format_log_message|log_message|logLevel|deallocate_|zerror|is_unrecoverable)" ".libs/libzookeeper_st.exp" > ".libs/libzookeeper_st.expT"
libtool: link: mv -f ".libs/libzookeeper_st.expT" ".libs/libzookeeper_st.exp"
libtool: link: echo "{ global:" > .libs/libzookeeper_st.ver
libtool: link:  cat .libs/libzookeeper_st.exp | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\1;/" >> .libs/libzookeeper_st.ver
libtool: link:  echo "local: *; };" >> .libs/libzookeeper_st.ver
libtool: link:  gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  -Wl,--whole-archive ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lm  -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libzookeeper_st.so.2 -Wl,-version-script -Wl,.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver -o .libs/libzookeeper_st.so.2.0.0
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: ignoring invalid character `\033' in script
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: ignoring invalid character `3' in script
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: ignoring invalid character `5' in script
/usr/bin/ld:.libs/libzookeeper_st.ver:2: syntax error in VERSION script
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libzookeeper_st.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/workspace/installs/zookeeper-3.4.6/src/c'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the version script it can't parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started looking (backwards from point of error) at the files being generated by libtool and there is a `grep` command which is screwing things up.

The output of the following command looks good:

```
$ /usr/bin/nm -B   ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a | sed -n -e 's/^.*[ ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[ ][ ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' | /bin/sed 's/.* //' | sort | uniq > .libs/libzookeeper_st.exp

$ head .libs/libzookeeper_st.exp
deallocate_ACL
deallocate_ACL_vector
deallocate_AuthPacket
deallocate_Buffer
deallocate_CheckVersionRequest
```

But, when `/bin/grep` is applied, the output has erroneous color codes:

```
$ /bin/grep -E -e "(zoo_|zookeeper_|zhandle|Z|format_log_message|log_message|logLevel|deallocate_|zerror|is_unrecoverable)" ".libs/libzookeeper_st.exp" > ".libs/libzookeeper_st.expT"

$ head .libs/libzookeeper_st.expT
ESC[1;35;40mESC[Kdeallocate_ESC[mESC[KACL
ESC[1;35;40mESC[Kdeallocate_ESC[mESC[KACL_vector
ESC[1;35;40mESC[Kdeallocate_ESC[mESC[KAuthPacket
ESC[1;35;40mESC[Kdeallocate_ESC[mESC[KBuffer
ESC[1;35;40mESC[Kdeallocate_ESC[mESC[KCheckVersionRequest
```

The funny thing is that if I use `/bin/grep --color=auto` instead of `/bin/grep`, things look fine.

So basically I ended up exporting `--color=auto` to `GREP_OPTIONS` which was previously set to `--color=always`:

```
$ echo $GREP_OPTIONS
--color=always

$ export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
```

And voila! Things worked!