# error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core` while building rust project for wasm32-unknown-unknown

Tags: rust, compilation, webassembly, rust-cargo, wasm-bindgen

I get the following error message:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `cfg-if`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

When I run this command:

```
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Comment: Are you sure that `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target is installed? If not, use `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` to install it.

Comment: `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`?

Answer (score 9):

There is a specialty about crates like `core` and `std` that is, since they are ubiquitous, they are used in some pre-compiled version instead of being build from source each time like other crates are. However, this only becomes apparent if you are cross compiling (i.e. using the `--target` flag).

There are essentially two options to solve this, and they are also explicitly stated in `rustc --explain E0463` ([online version](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#common-causes-for-missing-std-or-core)):

> - [if] You are cross-compiling for a target which doesn’t have `std` [or `core`] prepackaged. Consider one of the following:
>
>   - Adding a pre-compiled version of `std` [or `core`] with `rustup target add`
>   - Building `std` [or `core`] from source with cargo build `-Z build-std`

The first option (also already pointed-out by @Ivan and @Jmb) is probably the obvious
one:

```sh
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

The second option only works with a Nightly compiler and requires the `rust-src` component. But might be useful if you don't want to install each target, or if you are compiling against a custom target (i.e. `--target` with some JSON-file):

```sh
rustup +nightly component add rust-src
cargo +nightly build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -Z build-std=core
```

---

As a side note, the error message has improved in the current Nightly  Rust version as opposed to the current stable version (1.52). A Nightly compiler will print:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`
```

Comment: `error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Box`` and hundreds of others.

Comment: @chovy types like `Box` are part of the `alloc` crate not `core`, if you need `Box`es you either have to install the target `std` crate (e.g. via `rustup`) or you need to also compile `alloc` (e.g. via `build-std`) and provide an allocator yourself.